# two ajax on same page, but the second one is not getting whatever the first one has changed

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a main page, view.php. On this page, I have two ajax requests to two different pages. For example, I have

```
<script>
functionName1(someData1,someDiv1)
</script>
```

in the view.php. What it does is pass the data and div into a jQuery function, which would request another php file (php file 1) and pass in the data to create some HTML and MAKE SOME CHANGE IN THE DATABASE, and then echo out the HTML in the div.

Then somewhere after the above code, I have

```
<script>
functionName2(someData2,someDiv2)
</script>
```

in the view.php. It may pass some other data to another php file (php file 2) and create HTML and echo out in someDiv2.

Ajax 1 would make changes in the database and the HTML created by ajax 2 should reflect this change. But the problem is, it won't. The HTML seems like nothing has been changed in the database, but I know it's changed because I check the DB. I visit php file 2 and pass in the data by url, it can create the right HTML. So I don't understand why it won't work when I put those two ajax in the same page (view.php).

One thing I tried is to sleep for a couple of seconds in php file 2, and then it would create the right HTML which would reflect the database changes. So I'm wondering if the problem is the second ajax request is so close to the first one that the changes made by the first one is not saved by the DB (I myself highly doubt this, but what else).

Comment: AJAX calls are by default run asynchronously. Have you tried setting async: false to your ajax calls? This should force your first one to complete before the next gets sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter StaticVoid mentions, ajax calls are asynchronous.  What is most likely happening is that functionName1 is firing off its ajax call, followed very (*very*) shortly by functionName2 firing off its ajax call.  If you want the second call to happen only after the first one has returned, you will need to either a) make ajax synchronous, or b) put the call to functionName2 inside the callback of the ajax request in functionName1.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to ajax, please explain something to me: if I set both ajax synchronous, what will happen? a). the view.php will load as usual, the only waiting would be ajax2 waiting for ajax1 to finish; or b). view.php load up until where ajax1 happens, after ajax1 finishes, view.php continue to load up and stops where ajax2 happens and wait for ajax2 to finish

Comment: It depends on where you have the javascript code in the page source, and how functionName1 gets invoked.  If you use $(document).ready() as a way to trigger the first call, you will not block the loading and rendering of the page overall.  But in general that is why ajax is asynchronous by default.  If I were you, I would put the call to ajax2 inside the callback for ajax1.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would be a bit of a roundabout alternative of disabling async in your ajax calls but it might work for you.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
})
  .done(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "test2.html",
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

you have two options:

OPTION 1:

```
var functionName1=function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
    async:false //Set asynchronous as false
  });
}
//
var functionName2=function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
    async:false //Set asynchronous as false
  });
}
```

OPTION 2:

```
var functionName1=function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
    success: function(data){
       //Call he second function
       functionName2();
    }
  });
}
```